# How can i get average from EditText and show it on TextView like the image below?

Tags: android

I need to get average from those `EditText` and show average on `TextView`, and don't know how to do that.

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

To get data from any EditText
From the activity:

```
String data = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.putyourviewidhere)).getText().toString();
```

This gets the input in one edit view
You should then parse the input to a float for example

```
float dataAsFloat = Float.parseFloat(data);
```

Then you should repeat for all EditText, then make your calculation, then

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.putyouroutputviewidhere)).setText(Float.toString(result));
```

Comment: But i have this in a listview and i dont know who do get all  EditTexts  in positions, i think it can be done with a for loop but cant reach the last position from the last ( for(postion = 0; position <= ... ; position++){

.....

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you could add a TextWatcher via addTextChangedListener to every EditText in the Layout, and store the the text entered, as a number(int, float, double) of course, in a global variable, calculate the average and then set the text to the TextView.

But information about how are you storing the data of your app is required to give a better answer.

Comment: im doing this with a list view and i need to do a for loop and dont know how to get the last position of List

Comment: I hope your are using a custom ArrayAdapter<Float>, in it's getView(int, View, ViewGroup) method you get the position. How do you trigger the for loop?

Comment: i'm not using an ArrayAdapter<Float> i'm using a BaseAdapter, it that the problem ?

Comment: BaseAdapter is a abstract class, what's the instance it is referencing to?. You should use a concrete class like ArrayAdapter<T> or SimpleAdapter, by whatever mean, extending from it or creating a instance.